# Change Variable after and at a certain amount of time

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio

I want to have a PDF document displayed in my app. This PDF document is a schedule and there is a link for every day from Monday to Friday (5 links in total). That means I need to change the download link for the PDF document reader every day at, say 5pm.

My idea is to create a variable, this variable contains 5 strings, and every day the string is being changed to the next one in the list. When the list is finished, we start with the first link again.

How do I do this?

Comment: use a map, Calendar.SOMEDAY as key, link as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a HashMap where the 1st String is the day of the week and the 2nd String is your link/url.  Then you can figure out what day of the week it is and pull out your link:

```
    HashMap<String, String> linkMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    linkMap.put("Monday", "some link");
    linkMap.put("Tuesday", "some other link");
    // ...
    String weekDay;
    String link;
    SimpleDateFormat dayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.US);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    weekDay = dayFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    link = linkMap.get(weekDay);
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is working perfectly. One more question, If I want to update the link _at a certain time of the day_, do I just have to change the "EEE" in simpledateformat to, say "EEEH", and then change the "Mon" in the linkmap to "Mon17"? (So it will update every day on 17'o'clock)

Comment: Ask that as a separate question, but you're going to want to create an AlarmManager Object that does what you're wanting to do.  You'll also probably want to create a BootReceiver as the alarms you create will not persist past a device reboot.